# How to get data with Column name in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, database

I have XML file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ShippersDataSet xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/ShippersDataSet.xsd">
   <Shippers>
      <ShipperID>1</ShipperID>
      <CompanyName>Speedy Express</CompanyName>
      <Phone>(503) 555-9831</Phone>
   </Shippers>
   <Shippers>
      <ShipperID>2</ShipperID>
      <CompanyName>United Package</CompanyName>
      <Phone>(503) 555-3199</Phone>
   </Shippers>
   <Shippers>
      <ShipperID>3</ShipperID>
      <CompanyName>Federal Shipping</CompanyName>
      <Phone>(503) 555-9931</Phone>
   </Shippers>
</ShippersDataSet>
```

I have following input for XML data :

```
string XMLpath, string query
```

Query :

```
<Query>
   <ElementPath> Shippers</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

I need to add

Like following , ( I have achieved in SQL) same way I need to add for XML data

```
var list = new List<Myclassdef>();
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ... WHERE Col1=@param1", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", "value1");
        // ...
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Myclassdef data = new Myclassdef();
                data.Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    data.Data.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
                }
                list.Add(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have following input for XML data :

```
string XMLpath, string query
```

Query :

```
<Query><ElementPath> Shippers</ElementPath></Query>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Myclassdef>();
        var query = XDocument
            .Parse("<Query><ElementPath> Shippers</ElementPath></Query>");
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("xml.xml"));

        doc.Descendants(
            XName.Get(
                    query.Root.Value.Trim(),
                    doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(e =>
            {
                var data = new Myclassdef();
                data.Data = e
                    .Elements()
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        Name = c.Name.LocalName,
                        Value = (object)c.Value
                    })
                    .ToDictionary(c => c.Name, c => c.Value);
                list.Add(data);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: if query having empty string means . how to return all values ?

Comment: how to get all instead of query ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How to get all the descendant nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to XML for that (namespace System.Xml.Linq):

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(stream); // load the xml into an XDocument from a stream

// select the first of a specific element
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = from shippers in document.Descendants("Shippers") select shippers;
XElement element = (XElement)elements.First().FirstNode;

// loop through all the elements inside that element
foreach (XNode node in elements.First().Nodes())
{
   // do something with elements
}
```

Comment: how to return all document.Descendants ? instead of shippers alone ?

Comment: You can use the Descendants method without specifying a parameter.

Comment: then how to get node value and name inside for loop

Comment: Cast the node to type XElement like so: string value = ((XElement)node).Value